# Sitecore Azure vs Sitecore WebApp vs Sitecore on Azure PaaS

Tags: azure, paas

What is the difference between Sitecore Azure and Sitecore deployed on Azure PaaS. i.e. if I have Sitecore license and I procure an Azure PaaS server and install Sitecore on it, is it something different from Sitecore Azure.

Also if someone can point me to Sitecore Web App implementation document that will be really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, for documentation, you will probably want to bookmark this section of the docs: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/sitecore_on_azure

There is no current product named 'Sitecore Azure'. Sitecore did have something called this [in a previous version](https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/80/azure/getting_started_with_sitecore_azure). It was a first version of a PaaS model for Sitecore. It has been replaced by the current Sitecore on Azure PaaS offering.

You can also deploy IaaS into Azure, where you would deploy more traditionally and use Virtual Machines. The PaaS offering allows you to no longer take responsibility for the virtual machine/server/operating system and focus purely on the application level.

Comment: This answer is correct. Not trying to self-promote, but you can also find a step-by-step Sitecore 9.0.1 Deployment guide for Azure PaaS on my blog. https://sitecorehacker.com/2018/01/18/sitecore-9-0-1-on-azure-paas-deployment-guide

Comment: Really great step by step guide Pete

Comment: I will definitely follow this one. Thnx @pete